# How to install .bundle packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I've recently downloaded a package with .bundle extension. it's `VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle`. I want to install `vmware-player`, but when I open that, it opens with text editor.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

First be warned, installing files from outside of Ubuntu repository may compromise the system. VMware is probably safe, but it still should be mentioned.

1. You need to change permission of the file to make it executable:

   ```
   chmod a+x VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
   ```
2. Start the file. You will most probably need root privileges to install VMWare, but that is not always the case. So in this case:

   ```
   sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
   ```

Comment: Thanks!   Sigh.  If VMware would only say this on their Download page.....

Comment: Also you can `sudo /bin/sh VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `chmod u+x` rather than `chmod a+x'? New users shouldn't be encouraged to make something globally executable.

Comment: How to run `sudo` from Dolphin? if I right click on a file - there is no option to "Run as Root" (Run as Administrator). How to install VMWare without using a shell?

Comment: @eugene The only option I know to run `sudo` from dolphin is running dolphin with elevated access. As far as I'm concerned, `chmod a+x` and `chmod +x` are equivalent, see here:  https://www.systemconf.com/2020/12/25/using-chmod-x-command-on-linux-and-unix-with-examples/

Answer (score 54):

#### How to find out what kind of file it is?

The `.bundle` files for VMware Player, Workstation, and other products are actually shell scripts, with embedded binary data. You can discover or verify this with the [`file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/file.1.html) utility, which is handy for finding out what kind of file something (probably) is:

```bsh
ek@Ilex:~$ file VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle: a /usr/bin/env bash script executable (binary data)
```

#### How to use the file, based on this information?

You can [make it executable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) with [`chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chmod.1.html), then run it:

```bsh
chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
```

(If it's the only `.bundle` file in your current directory, you can just use `chmod +x *.bundle` and `./*.bundle`. Or type the first few characters of the filename and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the shell [will type the rest out for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion).)

#### Why `sudo`?

Virtualization software, such as VMware products, must be installed as root. This is why I put [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html) at the start of the second line. (In contrast to virtualization, *emulators* not employing any virtualization may generally be installed and used by a limited user, without any action by root.)

#### Why is plain `sudo` okay here, when the installer is graphical?

VMware product installers are graphical (at least for part of the installation). Although it's [generally recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application) to avoid running a graphical program with `sudo program` (preferring `gksudo program` or `sudo -H program`), *in this case it should be fine:*

- The VMware Player installer, and executable installers in general, are unlikely to attempt to write configuration files to the home directory of the user running them.
- And even if they did, the configuration files would pertain to the *installer* itself--they wouldn't prevent programs from being run normally by the limited user because you're unlikely to want to run such an installer as a non-root user.

Comment: It varies for different bundle files.  On Trusty, `file Downloads/VMw*` says
`VMware-Player-7.0.0-2305329.x86_64.bundle: data`   Instead you can see what the file starts with via ` cat -vt ~/Downloads/V*|more`   which shows it starts with a line indicating it is a shell script:  `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: VMware Installer additional Options `./VMware-Player-...x86_64.bundle --help`

Comment: Is it correct to run in with `/bin/sh` when file tells you `/usr/bin/env bash script executable`? This was suggested by [@thusitha sumanadasa](https://askubuntu.com/users/111471/thusitha-sumanadasa) in [a comment to the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/521205/830570) - or does it rarely make a difference whether you use `bash` or `sh`?