# ubuntu 19.10 cant install VMWare Workstation

Tags: software-installation, vmware

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my desktop. I am trying now to install VMWare Workstation but I keep getting error messages: sh: 0: Can't open VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle

Please can someone help me?

Comment: probably a double.... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/521199/how-to-install-bundle-packages-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have given executable permission to the `.bundle` file. Go to the folder in which the `.bundle` file is present, run the command `chmod +x VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle`. Now, run the installer using `./VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle`

Comment: Thanks, but no luck there:

John@john-desktop:~/Downloads$ chmod +x VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle chmod: cannot access 'VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle': No such file or directory john@john-desktop:~/Downloads$ ./VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle bash: ./VMware-Workstation-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle: No such file or directory

Any ideas? John

Comment: (vmware-installer.py:30997): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(vmware-installer.py:30997): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: New message - VMWare Workstation appears to have installed but I cant get it to finish installation and run - I get above messages in Terminal