# Not able to install the vmware-workstation in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-54-generic aarch64)

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, vmware

Getting Below error in the installation

Extracting VMware Installer...done.
/tmp/vmis.HSyzgr/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: line 420: /tmp/vmis.HSyzgr/install/vmware-installer/vmis-launcher: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: There’s very little here to work with. What steps did you follow to install the software before seeing this error?

Comment: ~/Downloads$ sudo sh VMware-Player-16.1.2-17966106.x86_64.bundle

Extracting VMware Installer...done.

Comment: This Ubuntu desktop is hosted on the Esxi which is hosted on the Rasberrypi

Comment: These details really need to be part of the question. Not providing them up front wastes your time as people ask you these things. Raspberry Pi questions are outside of my experience, but [this answer from a few years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/521205/1222991) might have something of value for you. Keep in mind that the Pi cannot run the same software as is found on most desktops and notebooks. An ARM variant is required.